# How to upload the Image to server in blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have tried the following code for image uploading,in this code am able to get the response from server but the image size is always zero in server.Can anyone help me about this regards,

```
  void App::uploadImage(){
 QString path(QDir::currentPath() + "/app/native/assets/Icon/img.jpg");
 QNetworkRequest request(
 QUrl( "http://domain.com?type=uploadimages&deviceid=12323"));
 QByteArray boundary = "-------------------------32142544626177"; 
 QFile file(path);
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
 qDebug() << "error read image";
 return;
 }
QByteArray fileContent(file.readAll());

 QByteArray data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
 data +=
 "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"img.jpg\";\r\n";
data += "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" + fileContent + "\r\n";
 data += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
  request.setRawHeader("Content-Type",
 "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
 request.setRawHeader("Content-Length",
 QString::number(data.size()).toAscii());
 file.close();
 qDebug() << "data" << data.size();
 QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 QNetworkReply *reply = am->post(request, "&data=" +data);

 QObject::connect(am, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,
 SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
void App::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    reply->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        QByteArray str = (reply->readAll());
        QString response = QString::fromUtf8(str.data(), str.size());
        qDebug() << " response " << response;
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "error response server";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
QString body = "" ;

const QUrl url("http://someurl.to/make/the/post" );
 QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
 QHttpPart textPartData;
 body = "" ;
 QTextStream(&body) << "";
 textPartData.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 textPartData.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"data\""));
 textPartData.setBody(body.toAscii());

     for(int i=0; i< number_of_files_to_send ; i++){
             QHttpPart imagePart;
             QString header_body = "";
             QTextStream(&header_body) << "form-data; name=\"" << name_of_the_file << "\"; filename=\"" << name_of_the_file << ".jpg\"" ;
             imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant(header_body));
             imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));

             //prepare file for upload
             QString filepath;
             QTextStream(&filepath) << FunkyPigeonBlackberry::getInstance()->dataModelProductDetails()->custom_image(i).value("cut_image").toString();

             // pack the new file
             QFile *file = new QFile(filepath);
             file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
             imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
             file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart
             multiPart->append(imagePart);
     }

 multiPart->append(textPartData);
 multiPart->append(textPartProductDetails);
 multiPart->append(textPartDataDelivery);


 QNetworkRequest request(url);

 QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->post(request, multiPart);
 connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onNetworkResponse()));
```